# Dynamic Python Array Slicing

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I am facing a situation where I have a VERY large `numpy.ndarray` (really, it's an hdf5 dataset) that I need to find a subset of quickly because they entire array cannot be held in memory.  However, I also do not want to iterate through such an array (even declaring the built-in numpy iterator throws a `MemoryError`) because my script would take literally days to run.

As such, I'm faced with the situation of iterating through some dimensions of the array so that I can perform array-operations on pared down subsets of the full array.  To do that, I need to be able to dynamically slice out a subset of the array.  Dynamic slicing means constructing a tuple and passing it.

For example, instead of

```
my_array[0,0,0]
```

I might use

```
my_array[(0,0,0,)]
```

Here's the problem:  if I want to slice out all values along a particular dimension/axis of the array manually, I could do something like

```
my_array[0,:,0]
> array([1, 4, 7])
```

However, I this does not work if I use a tuple:

```
my_array[(0,:,0,)]
```

where I'll get a `SyntaxError`.

How can I do this when I have to construct the slice dynamically to put something in the brackets of the array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could slice *automaticaly* using python's [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice):

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(3, 4, 5)
>>> a[0, :, 0]
array([ 0.48054702,  0.88728858,  0.83225113,  0.12491976])
>>> a[(0, slice(None), 0)]
array([ 0.48054702,  0.88728858,  0.83225113,  0.12491976])
```

The `slice` method reads as `slice(*start*, stop[, step])`. If only one argument is passed, then it is interpreted as `slice(0, stop)`.

In the example above `:` is translated to `slice(0, end)` which is equivalent to `slice(None)`.

Other slice examples:

```
:5 -> slice(5)
1:5 -> slice(1, 5)
1: -> slice(1, None)
1::2 -> slice(1, None, 2)
```

Comment: And you construct such a tuple dynamically if needed, as in the recent http://stackoverflow.com/q/36561777/901925

Comment: Thank you.  As you were posting I found the `slice(None)` use.  That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @hpaulj quite interesting (and related question) idd. Didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found an answer just as someone else did.

Suppose I have array:

```
my_array[...]
>array(
  [[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6],
    [ 7,  8,  9]],

   [[10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18]]])
```

I can use the `slice` object, which apparently is a thing:

```
sl1 = slice( None )
sl2 = slice( 1,2 )
sl3 = slice( None )
ad_array.matrix[(sl1, sl2, sl3)]
>array(
  [[[ 4,  5,  6]],

   [[13, 14, 15]]])
```